# Grep not found when call execl

Tags: c++, linux, grep, errno

I have here some code in C++. I want to execute the program grep in linux. When compiling, there are no errors.

```
com.append("grep");
execl(com.c_str(), "-n", "-w", word.c_str(), list_files.at(i + 1).c_str(), NULL);
```

But when I execute my c++-program, there were nothing. Then I wanted to find the error with errno.

The result was 2 and I know that this means that he couldn't find this program.

But what should I do so I can start grep from my c++-program ?

Answer (score 6):

`execl()` doesn't search `$PATH` for the executable.  Either give it the full path to the `grep` command, or use `execlp()` which does search `$PATH`.

`man execl` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the binary isn't found.

- check what com contains before appending (it should contain the proper path, like `/usr/bin/`, with a trailing path-separator...)
- try with "/usr/bin/grep" instead